# What cloud platform supports playframework 2.x deployments?

Tags: deployment, playframework, cloud, playframework-2.0, cloud-hosting

I know many platforms that currently support play 1.x but did any one have tried any that support play 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also [dotCloud](https://github.com/mchv/play2-on-dotcloud).

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend Heroku as The One (in capital letters). They are amazing, and provide excellent support for Play.

**BUT!** we aware that (unless I missed something last week) they still DO NOT SUPPORT WebSockets, arguably one of the major improvements in Play 2.0. So, if your application requires WebSockets, go with Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, you have :

- Heroku
- Cloudfoundry

EDIT : I'll add a bit of information about Play! cloud platforms. [Zenexity](http://zenexity.com), the company behind Play had a cloud platform for 1.x versions of Play! : [playapps](http://www.playapps.net/). They recently announced (1st may 2012) that they will close the platform. But they are suggesting a move to [Heroku](http://heroku.com) for all plays apps. As well for versions 1.x as 2.x.

Comment: Heroku is my cloud platform of choice; I've had nothing but good experiences with them.

Answer (score 2):

OpenShift

https://github.com/opensas/play2-openshift-quickstart

Comment: I tried this one but I got nowhere I think I should give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

Jelastic is a breath of fresh air.

And here is a tutorial: http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/07/02/play-2-web-application-deployment-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend openshift, here's a screencast showing how to do it
http://playlatam.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/deploying-play-framework-2-apps-with-java-and-scala-to-openshift/

and an article at red hat

https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/supporting-play-framework-on-openshift-with-the-diy-application-type